# is there is a way to use a huge image, in Yolov2 without pre-processing

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, object-detection

In most of object detection neural network, we use some pre-processing, and one operation is reduce the size of image, but when we reduce the size of an image, we lost pixels and features, I want to know if there is some way to process a huge image without reducing their size ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In order to forward a different image size in YOLOv2 you can simply change the input size in the network .cfg file:

```
[net]
...
height=416
width=416
...
```

However this will not necessarily give you better result and may lead to several issues:

1. The network is trained on images of certain size (or size interval) so changing the input size may lead to misses and/or misdetections. therefore you might need to fine-tune on large images.
2. Forwarding larger images may cause out of memory errors on your GPU.
3. The run time is slower.